# The entered value of TextFormFied disappears when navigating to another page and coming back

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want the TextFormFied value to persist even when navigating to another page and coming back.

I think it can be achieved by using Provider. but don't know how to update the **controller** with the proivder class instance variable.

Here is the code I tried.

TextFormField on UI

```
TextFormField(
  amountController: amountController,
  onChanged: (value){
    provider.amount(value);
  },
)),
```

Provider methode to get user entered value.

```
String? value ;

amount(String newAmount) {
  value = newAmount;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

I don't know whether it's correct or not.
Let me know how to update the `amountController` by `value`.

If this approach is wrong, Please let me know. What are the possible ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a stateful widget here, you could set text of your controller inside `initState` function like this:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  amountController.text = context.read<TestProvider>().value ?? '';
}
```

so when you get to this page, text field is initialized with the value from provider.

Comment: This approach works. Thank you! . Is there any approach to solving this problem?. I just want to improve my knowledge.

Comment: You could also call `addListener()` on the controller to listen to value changes, but when I tried to do it in `initState`, I got another error. If I could fix it I will definitely share it here.

Answer (score 0):

As you have attached very less code, let's see you have done these below things right:

1. Created a Model class:
   model class that holds the state you want to persist. This will be the class you provide using `ChangeNotifierProvider`, with having a function which will save the value and notify the listeners.
2. Wrapped your widget tree with Provider, simple thing.
3. Saving the value and using it with the help of Provider:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: amountController,
              onChanged: (value) {
                Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false).updateAmount(value);
              },
            ),
            Text('Amount: ${Provider.of<MyModel>(context).amount}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've created a model class. The reason to attach only one method is for simplicity. I want to ask a question about ur code. Why do u update the value in the `Text()`? Is it not possible to update the `TextFormField()`? .That was my question.

Comment: No, you got it wrong, `Provider.of<MyModel>(context).amount` is an veriable of that class containing the amount, whereas `Provider.of<MyModel>(context).updateAmount(value)` is a function which take the value and update the `amount` variable of `MyModel` and notify the listeners. Let me know if you still don't understand, i can put code for model class as well.

Comment: My question is why do u disaply the amount value in `Text()` . I want the value is disaply in the `TextFormField()`

Comment: Ooh sorry mate, then you just need to give that value to your textEditingController in the `initState` of your class.

Comment: Yes, It works as @M.Mahdi Nabiollahi and you said. Thank you!